# How to find out if entered integers in a matrix make it a magic square?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I need to use multiple methods to find out if the numbers in a matrix, entered by the user, make it a magic square (ie all rows, columns, and diagonals have an equal sum). For some reason, I can not figure out how to add up the sum of each diagonal and compare them to each other in my second method. I also need to come up with one method to find the sum of each row and compare them to one another for equivalency. Then I need to make another method just like the one with the rows, except with the columns instead.

```
/**
 * all rows, columns, and diagonals = the same sum
 *
 * @author Jenny Nguyen
 * @version 5-6-19
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MagicSquare
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        //Declare + initialize
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size;

        //asks user how big square will be
        System.out.println("How many rows and columns will there be in the square?");
        size = input.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];
        //calls up method
        read2D(matrix, input);
        System.out.println("The square looks like this: ");
        //pritns matrix
        for (int row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col=0; col< matrix[row].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print (matrix[row][col] + "\t"); //print the item
            }
            System.out.println(); //go to next line for next row
        }
        //calls up other method

        //prints if it's a magic square or not
        if (diagonals(matrix, size) == false)
            System.out.println("This is not a magic square.");
        else if (diagonals(matrix,size) == true) //if method compare(matric) == true
            System.out.println("This is a magic square.");
        else
            System.out.println("try again");
        //program needs to work for square of any size and values
    }
    //Method 1
    /**
     * asks user to enter numbers in the square
     *
     * @param int[][]  
     * @return    none
     */
    public static void read2D(int [][]  matrix, Scanner input)
    {
        for (int row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col=0; col< matrix[row].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print ("Please enter an integer: "); //prompt user
                matrix[row][col] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    //Method 2
    /**
     * determine whether diagonals are equal or not
     *
     * @param int[][] matrix, int size
     * @return    none
     */
    public static boolean diagonals(int [][]  matrix, int size)
    {
        int dia1=0;
        for (int i=0, j=0; i<size && j<size; i++, j++) 
        {
            //adds diagonal integers left to right
            dia1 += matrix[i][j];
        }
        int dia2=0;
        for (int i=0,j=size-1 ; i<size && j>=0 ; i++, j--)
        {
            //adds diagonal integers right to left
            dia2 += matrix[i][j];
        }
        if (dia1==dia2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What is the question?

Comment: I'm wondering the issue with my 2nd method labelled diagonals. Along with how to figure out comparing the sum of the rows with each other

Answer (score 0):

Primary diagonal in square : index of row is equal of index of column

Secondary diagonal in square: sum of row and column indexes is equal to matrix size

Here is the method(works in matrix where rows == cols):

```
public void diagonalsSum(int[][] matrix, int size) {
        int primaryDiagonalSum = 0;
        int secondaryDiagonalSum = 0;
        if (rows == cols) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    if (i == j) {
                        primaryDiagonalSum += matrix[i][j];
                    }
                    if (i + j == size) {
                        secondaryDiagonalSum += matrix[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Primary diagonal sum = " + primaryDiagonalSum);
        System.out.println("Secondary diagonal sum = " + secondaryDiagonalSum);
}
```

Here is the method for sum of every row, adapt code for your needs and compare each row to another.

```
public void sumOfRows(int[][] matrix, int size) {
        int[] rowsSum = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                rowsSum[i] += matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        int i = 1;
        for (int sum : rowsSum) {
            System.out.println("Sum of row " + (i++) + " = " + sum);
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much I'll check it out!